# Why is vector not working inside class c++?

Tags: c++, class, vector

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class Solution
{
public:
    std::vector<std::int> test(26, -1);
};
```

Can somebody please tell why is this showing error

```
test.cpp:6:22: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
     vector<int> test(26, -1);
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` is bad.  Don't do that.

Comment: `int` is not defined in `std`. Just use `int`.